# static_assert doesn't work as expected when using std::is_same, std::result_of and std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

I'm experiencing a weird behavior when using `static_assert` for asserting that the return type of a `function object` is the same as another type. Something like (This code is just for presenting the problem and not actually what i'm trying to do).

```
int foo() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    auto funcObj = std::bind(foo);
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::result_of<funcObj()>, int>::value, "FuncObj return type is not int");
    return 0;
}
```

The assertion fails. What's going wrong here?

Comment: I guess you meant: `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(funcObj()), int>::value, "FuncObj return type is not int");`

Comment: Please post actual code that actually generates the error message in question.  When something happens that you don't understand, simplifying is quite likely to delete the part that makes it happen if you do not **test** that the simplification did not delete the part that makes it happen.

Answer (score 3):

`std::result_of<?>` is a useless type to use directly.

`typename std::result_of<?>::type` and `std::result_of_t<?>` (in C++14) what you want.

An easy way to get a good error message for this kind of thing is:

```
std::result_of<decltype(funcObj)()> x = 3;
```

which should generate error messages that make it clear that the lhs type is not `int` like you expected.  (cannot convert `int` to '*some complex type*' usually).

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::result_of<funcObj()>, int>::value, "FuncObj return type is not int");
```

needs to be

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::result_of<decltype(funcObj)()>::type, int>::value, "FuncObj return type is not int");
        // Missing pieces  ^^^^^^^^                                 ^^ ^^^^^^
```